# I want to call Default camera using "MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE" and start default camera in focus mode "MACRO"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I Want to start Default Camera using this code...
But when camera start i want to start camera with default setting in focus mode as "MACRO" mode.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);        
startActivity(intent);
```

Start Camera Activity at that time it get settings of focus mode as "MACRO".
I Want get Just settings of camera how it can be set......
How set "MACRO" focus mode when i call camera using intent.

Comment: instead of startActivity(intent) just use startActivityForResult(intent,1);